# How do i check how long a vbs window was open for?

Tags: vbscript

I want to make a game where you have to press the button as fast as possible. I have the loop for the box set up, but I have no idea how to track how long this window was open for and place it in a variable.

```
Do
    X = MsgBox("Press the button as fast as possible! (last time:)", 0+0, "Click! Click! Click!")
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the time before and after displaying the message box:

```
Do
    t1 = Timer * 1000  'milliseconds
    x = MsgBox(...)
    t2 = Timer * 1000  'milliseconds
    delta = t2 - t1
Loop
```